# How can I get the values of multiple textboxes and store them in a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a page that calculates all your hours worked. However, I can't get it to output anything. I've tried to use `querySelectorAll` and `getElementsByTagName` (by changing the class tag to name in the textbox's).

But when I execute I get "undefined" instead of numbers.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```js
function calcHours() {
      let hoursWorked = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll(".txtBox1").value);
      const hoursWorkedText = "Hours worked: "

      if (Number.isNaN(hoursWorked)) {
        //code to throw error.
  errorCalc("value is not a number");
      }
      else {
        //code to run normally.
  document.getElementById('hoursTotal').innerHTML = hoursWorked;
  document.getElementById('hrWorkTxt').innerHTML = hoursWorkedText;
      }
    }
 
 function errorCalc(errorTxt) {
  alert("You done goofed, " + errorTxt + " error");
 }
```

```html
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<p id="hrWorkTxt">
<p id="hoursTotal">
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calcHours()">
```

Comment: use the `.value` property rather than `.innerHTML`

Comment: Try `const hoursWorked = [...document.querySelectorAll(".txtBox1")].reduce((acc, x) => acc + parseInt(x.value, 10), 0);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple initial notes:

1. There is no type `textbox` for inputs. You probably mean `text`. Since you want to calculate numbers i think you should use the type `number`. This way you can skip checking if the input is NAN etc...
2. Since you dealing with more than one input, in order to get all values you should first iterate all of them and then get each value.

Anyway i think this is what you trying to do:

```js
function calcHours() {
  let hoursWorked = document.querySelectorAll(".txtBox1");
  let hoursWorkedTotal =0;
  for (let i = 0; i < hoursWorked.length; i+=1) {
    hoursWorkedTotal += parseInt(hoursWorked[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('hoursTotal').innerHTML = hoursWorkedTotal;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="txtBox1" value="0" />
<input type="number" class="txtBox1" value="0" />
<input type="number" class="txtBox1" value="0" />
<input type="number" class="txtBox1" value="0" />
<input type="number" class="txtBox1" value="0" />
<input type="number" class="txtBox1" value="0" />
<input type="number" class="txtBox1" value="0" />
<button type="button" onclick="calcHours()">Calculate</button>
<p id="hoursTotal"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and also your notes. I was taught by my college tutor very recently to do it as textbox, but as I've learned, not everything he's taught is best practice so I'm glad for people like you.

Answer (score 0):

The `document.querySelectorAll(".txtBox1")` instruction returns an `array` of elements so it is not possible to access to `.value` property in the way you are trying.

You should iterate the element of the returning `array` in this way:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".txtBox1");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  // do something with elements[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing the `p` element with `.innerHTML`, try `.value`.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll(".txtBox1")` returns an object so you have to get the data from it.

I think the following code will work for you.

```js
function calcHours() {
      let hoursWorked = document.querySelectorAll(".txtBox1");
   let hoursWorkedTotal =0;
   for (var i=0; i<hoursWorked.length; i++){
   //console.log(hoursWorked[i].value);
    hoursWorkedTotal += parseInt(hoursWorked[i].value);
   }
   
      const hoursWorkedText = "Hours worked: "

      if (Number.isNaN(hoursWorked)) {
        //code to throw error.
        errorCalc("value is not a number");
      }
      else {
        //code to run normally.
        document.getElementById('hoursTotal').innerHTML = hoursWorkedTotal;
        document.getElementById('hrWorkTxt').innerHTML = hoursWorkedText;
      }
    }

    function errorCalc(errorTxt) {
        alert("You done goofed, " + errorTxt + " error");
    }
```

```html
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<input type="textbox" class="txtBox1">
<p id="hrWorkTxt">
<p id="hoursTotal">
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calcHours()">
```